# How is phase matching equivalent to momentum conservation?

Tags: laser, non-linear-optics

I am studying about phase matching and how it is being used to maximise the output power in various experiments. But I am not able to understand how can phase matching be equivalent to momentum conservation. Can anyone explain me with an example of possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to understand how does Phase matching establish momentum conservation. I know that when we are dealing with non-linear processes we want phase matching do ensure maximum energy transfer so that we can get maximum energy conversion efficiency but how does this leads to the condition of momentum conservation is confusing me.

Comment: k-vector is momentum of light. i.e. its a pillar of physics that energy and momentum need to be conserved. Which means that there is the need to satisfy that in the system: photon energies must be conserved and so does the whole momentum. As $\omega$ is independent of medium, then you need to match the k-vectors, or momentum. As you recall, $k\cdot r$ is a phase term for the E-field. So, when conserving momentum you are additionally matching the phase terms of the fields.